# I am almost there...PhoneGap Android connect to WCF Service

Tags: android, wcf, jquery, cordova, jsonp

Firstly I would like to thank all the experts here on stackoverflow, by reading questions asked and looking at example code and reading the answers i have been able to get to this point. Thank you once again!

I have been spending hours and hours searching for a solution, I’ve read through many posts on this issue.  It’s seem this is a issue a lot of others are/has been struggling with.I would highly appreciate any more advise or tips if somebody can assist in this frustrating issue.

All my development are done on my local machine. (Win 7, Visual Studio 11beta)

A WCF Service is hosted in IIS Express on its own port or IIS 7.5 (.Net Framework 4.0)

Second Web Application with only Html5/jQuery is hosted in IIS Express on a different port.

Using Eclipse 3.7.2 with Android SDK 17 also on my local machine.
Its seem all the software are functioning properly.
Android Emulator is working,  Phonegap/Cordova library is installed, etc.
I am using Android 4.0.3 with Cordova 1.6.0

I am asking assistance to find out why my phonegap emulator ajax call won’t go through to my WCF REST Service. I don’t have a actual android device now  to test the program on at this moment therefore I must use the Emulator.

Some more detail:

I have a WCF REST Service developed in .Net receiving & sending in JSON and JSON-P.

I have tested this with a second web application on a different port to make sure cross domain calls are allowed.

I have also used the RESTclient plugin for Firefox and can use it to make JSON and JSON-P calls successfully. [ http://restclient.net/ ]
So I am sure the WCF Service is working as it should. There shouldn't be any cross domain issue.

When I take the Html file with jQuery that I know is working within Visual Studio, to eclipse, copy into phonegap app, I  try to make a basic call to my WCF server and I am unable to connect to the server.

I have changed the URL from [http://localhost:50425/LoginService.svc/GetData] to  [http://10.0.2.2:50425/LoginService.svc/GetData] 
according to android documentation : [http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses]

I have created an allow all whitelist with the following setting:

[ access origin="*" ]

within the cordova.xml file. See: [http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/05/15/Whitelisting-Domains-in-Cordova-_2800_PhoneGap_2900_-Android.aspx]

The correct permissions have been set inside the AndroidManifest.xml file according to  [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android]

When I initiate the call, I use  $.ajaxSetup error function to trap network error etc. and display with alert the error message.  Used console.log() to make sure it passes this function without a error.

When the call actually happens, I receive a "Bad Request - Invalid Host Name. HTTP 400. The request hostname is invalid."

If the call would have been successful, I use breakpoints inside Visual Studio to know for certain the call has been made and see the request coming through.

Is there any other ways to test from emulator if I can access the "external" host? In this case to make sure emulator actually can find the service? 
Is there any tools or other configuration settings that needs to be done?

I have even deleted my emulator and created a new one but it still fails to connect to the WCF Service.

I would really like this to work, would like to build a complete phonegap application but can’t continue if I can't make a call to a web service.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have developed a PhoneGap App which utilized a RESTful WebService. You should step through your js code with a browser, either firefox w/firebug or chrome. If that works np, there may be some issues with the emulator making the calls. Maybe some settings?

Comment: Hi furier, Thank you for the reply. I agree it must be a setting inside the emulator, cos the app itself works with jsonp callback inside visual studio. just want to proof that i can get data from web server in phonegap so i can continue with development...

Comment: Well my guess is that you use JQuery for querying the web-service so you are actually not using PhoneGap for this purpose. Then its not a PhoneGap js problem atleast, idk if it may be some settings in the PhoneGap wrapper project or the emulator, but one of those would be my guess.

Comment: Thank you for the advise! OK it seems i found the issue. You are right. Its not Phonegap or jQuery. It is the fact that emulator won't connect to my IIS Express but to IIS installed on local machine. Change the url to point to iis and my jquery ajax call was recieved and it returned jsonp data. Dont know why it (emulator) wont connect to iis express. Thank you very much taking the time to help resolve my issue. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap is really just a wrapper for html/css/js webpages with a js library for accessing phone specific functionality, which can be compiled to multiple native mobile platform apps.

So this is really not a PhoneGap issue...

You say you are using JQuery to query your web service, if you can open the html file which fires of the request in your normal browser window, and everything works fine. The problem is not with the code, but with the Emulator you are using, maybe some miss configurations idk.

Okay if that still fails, you are most likely pointing to the wrong/no IIS Instance.
If you have two IIS Instances running on port 80 idk how that will behave, but i don't think that will work very well, my guess is that one of them will override the other one.

So if you are hosing your webservice on IIS 1, but IIS 2 overrides IIS 1, then you will never reach the webservice, and get the error you get.

So when you changed to point to the other IIS Instance, it started working again.

Comment: Thanks mate for the help. yeah should have know it was something simple. you are right. i used different instance and ports on IIS to simulate the whole cross domain issue. wanted to be sure i had it working before going to production environment. just very glad i finally got it to work from within phonegap. Only connect to port 80 on local IIS (not express). learned something new which is always good. once again, thank you :)